# I have handled alert in selenium java it is working fine . When i run local but while azure pipeline execution this alert is not handled shows error

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have handled alert in selenium java it is working fine . When i run local but while azure pipeline execution this alert is not handled shows error ...

*TimeoutException:Expected condition is failed : waiting for alert to be present tried for 20seconds with 500 ms intervals.*

Not sure why i am getting this. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you ran the tests directly on the agent and saw whether the alert is thrown?

Comment: Did you try with headless mode in local? getting same error? or pass?

Comment: When i open rdp in machine it works in pipeline

Comment: but if i run alone pipeline i am not able to